# List Not Removing Values

Tags: python, list

I have no clue why values in one list are not being removed with this code. I am wondering if any of you guys see the problem.

```
data = list(csv.reader(open("nyse.csv")))
sofar = os.listdir('C:/Users/lucia/Downloads')
for x in range(len(sofar)):
    sofar[x] = sofar[x][:-4]
print(sofar)
bdata = []
for x in data:
    bdata.append(x[0])
print(bdata)
for x in bdata:
    for y in sofar:
        if x == y:
            bdata.remove(x)
print(bdata)
```

The output of the print statements:

```
sofar = ['A', 'AAN', 'AAP', 'AAT', 'AB', 'ABB', 'ABBV', 'ABC', 'ABEV', 'ABG', 'ABM', 'ABR', 'ABT', 
        'ACC', 'ACCO', 'ACE', 'ACG', 'ACH', 'ACI', 'ACM', 'ACN', 'ACP'...]
bdata(before for loop changes) = ['A', 'AA', 'AA$B', 'AAC', 'AAN', 'AAP', 'AAT', 'AAV', 'AB', 'ABB', 
                                 'ABBV', 'ABC'...]
bdata(after for loop, any value in "sofar" should not exist here) = ['AA', 'AA$B', 'AAC', 'AAP', 'AAV', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABG', 'ABR', 'ABR$A', 'ABR$B', 'ABR$C', 'ABRN'...]
```

The first occurrence that a value in "sofar" is not removed from "bdata" is the value 'AAP'. This makes no sense and I've looked over it many times. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually shouldn't add or remove items from a list or other data structure at the same time you iterate over it. To remove items in list `A` which are present in list `B` try something like:

```py
filtered_A = [e for e in A if e not in B]
```

or in your case,

```py
bdata = [e for e in bdata if e not in sofar]
```

It is OK to overwrite your old list with the same name (`bdata`) if you don't care about preserving the original `bdata` list. Otherwise just pick a different name.

Comment: I have tried this solution and I have even tried to do the inverse of what I did which would be to find all x != y and then I would append those to a new list. I still have the same problem with this new list not having values that should be in it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of bdata and change your for loop as shown below:

```
bdata_copy = list(bdata)
for x in bdata_copy:
    if x in sofar:
        bdata.remove(x)
print(bdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the other answer has a much nicer way of implementing it that does the same thing as mine.

In python (and most other programming languages) avoid removing items of the list you are looping over. You could make a copy of the list and loop over that.

```py
data = list(csv.reader(open("nyse.csv")))
sofar = os.listdir('C:/Users/lucia/Downloads')
for x in range(len(sofar)):
    sofar[x] = sofar[x][:-4]
print(sofar)
bdata = []
for x in data:
    bdata.append(x[0])
print(bdata)
copy_of_bdata = [item for item in bdata] # use a list comprehension to reconstruct the list
for x in copy_of_bdata:
    for y in sofar:
        if x == y:
            bdata.remove(x)
del copy_of_bdata # optional
print(bdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you don't want to delete values from a list you are iterating over.

To resolve that problem, iterate over the other list:

```
for x in sofar:
    # use 'if' if there are no duplicate values
    while x in bdata:
        bdata.remove(x)
```

Edit: I changed the if to while in case there are duplicate values. If there aren't duplicate values, make that an if statement. The while version is not a great idea as it doesn't remember where it left off when it looks for the second occurance of x.

Edit: better to use a list comprehension as suggested by @smarchese